# Инициализация динамического двумерного массива. Почему так делать нельзя?

Tags: указатели, c++

Здравствуйте! Объясните пожалуйста, почему так выделять память для t нельзя?

```
int **t;
(t-1)=new int *[5];
```

Компилятор выдает:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Мне нужно чтобы в t-1 находился адрес указателя на int. И чтобы например обратившись по адресу t[-1][1] я получил значение лежащее в указателе (*(t-1)+1). Как это осуществить?

Comment: Очень плохая идея

Comment: @mikillskegg Чем же она плоха? (Я новичок)

Comment: @mikillskegg Окей пусть хотя бы вот так будет

    t=new int *[m+2];
    (*t+1)=new int[n];

Но как разобраться со второй строкой???

Comment: А "в t-1" -- это где? Арифметика указателей в C/C++ -- это другое обозначение операции индексирования. *t -- содержимое ячейки по адресу t, а вот что значит (t-1)? И с точки зрения синтаксиса это не "левое выражение", которое может находиться слева от операции присваивания, а правое.

Comment: @alexlz Хорошо, а что если сделать так?

    int **t;
    int **p;
    p=*(t-1);
    p=new int *[n];

Щас попробую...

Comment: >Хорошо, а что если сделать так?

 Перезапишешь значение, присвоенное в 3-й строке, значением полученным в результате выделения памяти. То есть, 3-я строка лишняя и ничего не делает.

Comment: В третьей строке значение t не определено. Да и по количеству разыменований (или уровней указателей) бяка. *(t-1) имеет тип int*, а p -- int**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если уж очень хочется так сделать, то, думаю, надо сделать так

```
int **t;
t=new int *[5];
t++;
```

Тогда можно будет к обращаться к первому элементy

```
t[-1][0]
```

Но помните, что освобождать память тоже нужно

```
delete [] (t-1);
```

Comment: ДА ДАА ДА А!!! СПАСИБО! Я забыл совсем про это!

Answer (score 4):

Выражение (t-1) - это результат вычисления, называемый rvalue. Его можно использовать только для того, чтобы сохранить или разыменовать. Временному значению нельзя (и нет смысла) ничего присваивать, так как оно теряется. Сделать элемент -1 доступным можно, сдвинув указатель на один элемент вперёд.

```
int** t=new int*[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    t[i]=new int[5];
t++;
t[-1][1]=666;
//Не забудь удалить выделенную память
```

То же самое можно провернуть и с обычным массивом:

```
int data[5][5];
int** t=data+1;
t[-1][1]=666;
```

И всё-таки так лучше не делать. Зачем тебе отрицательные индексы понадобились? Я уже больше 2 лет программирую, и мне ни разу не нужны были отрицательные индексы массивов.

P. S. Ну вот, опередили...

Comment: Вам тоже огромнейшее спасибо.

Comment: Да ерундой маюсь, хочу сделать поверхность тора, для автомата Жизнь.

Comment: Но при этом хочу сам до этого дойти. Не без вашей помощи конечно :)))

Answer (score 1):

Поиграться со звездочками, скобками и смещениями адресов иногда увлекательно.

Например, навеяно Вашим вопросом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  int **t = malloc(5*sizeof(int *));
  t++;
  *(t-1) = malloc(5*sizeof(int *));
  t[-1][0] = 20;
  *((*(t-1))+2) = 30;
  printf ("%d %d\n",**(t-1),t[-1][2]);
  exit (0);
}
```

Безусловно непонятный (без расшифровки) код. Но работает, печатает 20 30.

А писать лучше так, чтобы другим (и себе через полгода) сразу было понятно. Зачем  в торе отрицательные индексы, не понимаю. Там просто  их изменения надо вычислять через операцию **%**.

Comment: >Безусловно непонятный (без расшифровки) код.

 Ещё к тому же с небольшим багом. При компиляции под x64 будет жрать на 20 байт больше, чем мог бы без этого бага.

Comment: Если честно, не понял. Делаем "двумерный массив" [5][5]. На самом деле вектор указателей на 5 строк, каждая 5 элементов ("столбцов"). 
К строкам можно обращаться по индексам от -1 до 3. 

-

Откуда 20 байт в x64 ? Объясните, плз.

Если Вы о разнице в размере указателей в x32 и x64, то какой же это  баг ? Или Вы имели в виду, что надо разместить в памяти **действительно двумерный** массив ? 

Тогда работать с ним по индексам не получится.

Comment: Баг в третьей строке функции main. Ты выделяешь память для 5 указателей на int и результат присваиваешь переменной типа `int*`. Это аналогично коду

    *(t-1)=(int*)new int*[5];

 Вот, как должно быть:

    *(t-1)=new int[5]; //В стиле C++
    *(t-1)=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int)); //В стиле C

 Компилятор C++ не скомпилирует твой код, потому что malloc возвращает `void*`, а он неявно не приводится к `int*`. Но в C должно работать, так как он переводит `void*` в любые типы указателей.

Comment: Уважаемый @GLmonster ! 

А в чем разница ? Весь код (в стиле C) приведите, что бы ясно было о чем Вы пишете.